# Python 3 Picross Board Print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I´m doing a project that requires me to create a picross game without a GUI. I´m having trouble with a function that prints the picross board and i need help.
I´m supposed to print this:

[image: Picross board]

this is my current code and the intern representation of the board is board=[(specifications tuple), [list with created cells] the created cells are zero by default and i have a separate function to create them with the tuple of tuples as argument (note that the tuple of tuples length is 2 and the board size is determined by the tuples length, len(specifications tuple[0]), if the length is 3, then the board is 3x3, for example):

```
t=[(((1,), (3,), (1,)), ((3,), (1,), (1,))), [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]]]
board_size = len(t[0][0])
cells = t[1]
hnums = t[0][1]
vnums = t[0][0]

h1 = [x[1] if len(x) > 1 else " " for x in hnums]
h2 = [x[0] for x in hnums]
v1 = [x[1] if len(x) > 1 else " " for x in vnums]
v2 = [x[0] for x in vnums]

heading_string = "  {}  " * board_size
print(heading_string.format(*h1))
print(heading_string.format(*h2))

def cell_text(c):
    if c == 0:
        return "?"
    elif c == 1:
        return "."
    else:
        return "X"

row = []
for i in t[1]:
    for x, cell in enumerate(i, 1):
        row.append(cell_text(cell))
        if x % board_size == 0:
            row_string = "[ {} ]" * board_size
            vnum_string = " " + str(v2[(x) // board_size])+ " " \
                + str(v1[(x) // board_size]) + "|"
            print(row_string.format(*row) + vnum_string)
            row = []
```

the problem is that the tuples inside the tuple t[0] vary in lenght and for this code i can only print if the lenght is 2. this is the output

```
        1    3    1
      [ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 3  |
      [ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 3  |
      [ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 3  |
```

It needs to be formatted like this:

```
  1    3    1
[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 3|
[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 3|
[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 3|
```

or for example for this board specifications t=[(((1, 2), (1,), (1, 1)), ((1, 2), (1,), (1, 1))), [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]] the output should be like this:

```
  1         1    
  2    1    1    
[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 1 2|
[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 1  |
[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 1 1|
```

Also the board size depends on t[0][0] length

```
  z
  x     x     x     x     x
[ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] y  |
[ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] y  |
[ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] y  |
[ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] y  |
[ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] [ ? ] y z|
```

Comment: If you want an urgent answer, you should add a reward to your question, not an "URGENT" at the end of your title

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing i can give you back except for my gratitude... I would reward you otherwise that´s for sure

Comment: By reward, i mean stackoverflow's bounty

Comment: whats that? I´m new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this

```
tablero_data1 = [(((1,), (3,), (1,)), ((3,), (1,), (1,))), [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]]]
tablero_data2 = [(((1, 2), (1,), (1, 1)), ((1, 2), (1,), (1, 5))), [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0]]]

def print_board(board_data:"[border,inside]"):
    """border = (rows,columns)
       inside = [ [int] ]
       columns = ( espesication, )
       rows = ( espesication, )
       espesication = (int,)"""
    (rows,columns),inside = board_data 
    board_size = len(columns)
    nivel_columns = max(map(len,columns))
    nivel_rows = max(map(len,rows))
    rows    = tuple(map(lambda x: x+(" ",)*nivel_rows,rows))
    inside  = list(map(lambda f:f[:board_size],inside))
    columns = tuple(map(lambda esp:tuple(reversed(esp)),columns))
    for i in reversed( range(nivel_columns) ):#print columns info
        for esp in columns:
            if len(esp)>i:
                print("  %d  "%esp[i],end="")
            else:
                print( "     ",end="")
        print()
    for j,fila in enumerate(inside):#print rows
        print("".join(map(lambda i: "[ %s ]"%cell_text(i),fila)) +" "+ " ".join(map(str,rows[j][:nivel_rows]))+"|" )


print_board(tablero_data1)
print()
print_board(tablero_data2)
```

output

```
  3    1    1  
[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 1|
[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 3|
[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 1|

  1         1  
  2    1    5  
[ ? ][ . ][ ? ] 1 2|
[ ? ][ ? ][ X ] 1  |
[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ] 1 1|
```

Comment: copperfield thanks a lot for the answer but in tablero_data2 you have [(((.......)), ((1, 2)...))),... when you print this in the column it should be the 1 on top, how can i change this?

Comment: and the first tuple corresponds to the lines and the second tuple to the columns

Comment: oh, I though it was (columns, row) fixed. Llike that?

Comment: some names translate to English just in case, (because my main language is Spanish)

Comment: im portuguese so for example "nivel"helped me understand what you meant, but i cant seem to understand what happens in some lines, can you comment the code, you can do it in spanish i understand it aswell

Comment: I forgot to tell you that if the numbers inside the rows are 0, it must print [ ? ] on the inside and if it is 1 it must print [ . ] and else it must print [ X ]. I´ve tried doing it but i cant

Comment: sure, what part you don't understand?

Comment: i need to print [ ? ] if inside the board cell the number is zero and print [ . ] if the number is 1 and else print [ X ], how can i do it?

Comment: i tried doing this:                                                                                              for j,fila in enumerate(rows):#print rows
        for x in t[1]:
            for z in x:
                if z==0:
                    print("".join("[ ? ]"*board_size) +" "+ " ".join(map(str,rows[j][:nivel_rows]))+"|" )
                elif z==1:
                    print("".join("[ . ]"*board_size) +" "+ " ".join(map(str,rows[j][:nivel_rows]))+"|" )
                else:
                    print("".join("[ X ]"*board_size) +" "+ " ".join(map(str,rows[j][:nivel_rows]))+"|" )

Comment: sorry i cant indent here

Comment: change "[ %d ]"%i for  "[ %s ]"%cell_text(i)

Comment: it says cell_text is not defined

Comment: i created a new function defining cell text but the board is out of format

Comment: use the old one, with that I get the ouput that I put in the last edit

Comment: still says cell_text is not defined

Comment: oh ok sorry for that! thanks a lot bro you helped me a lot really!

Comment: still want that I put some comment to the code, or you already understand all the function?